# Single Email Multiple Recipients

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-studio

Is there a 'group' email function available through MC?

We have organizations in our database with up to 10 contacts associated with them.  It would be ideal if there was a singular email with multiple contacts in the `To:` field.  This would circumvent the feeling that it was just a mass send.

ie.  An email being sent from MC to an organization would have multiple email addresses in the TO: field.

[image]

Comment: you should look into the CC and BCC options.  I am not sure it is easily made dynamic via UI, but it should be possible via API.

Answer (score -1):

[image]@Tom Callahan see the image you can get some clarify

Comment: Updated to include image.  
Not looking to send multiple tests but to actually send a "group email" with multiple recipients on the same email.